# how to automatically update ical events (Rails) daily

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refresh, icalendar

I am working on a website where users can subscribe via webcal to a calendar feed. 
The events change daily. When events get updated/deleted/created this should be synced on the users local calendar accordingly.

If the user chooses to automatically update every day on the calendar app, I understand that the calendar app will periodically poll the calendar's URL to check for updates.

How does this exactly work on a technical level?

Code (Rails):

Controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.ics do
        cal = Icalendar::Calendar.new
        cal.x_wr_calname = 'My Calendar'
        events.each do |event|
        cal.event do |e|
            e.dtstart     = event.start_time
            e.dtend       = event.end_time
            e.summary     = "Calendar #{Area.where(area_code: events.first.area_code).first.name}"
            e.description = "placeholder"
         end
        end
        cal.publish
        render plain: cal.to_ical
      end
    end
```

and in the html

```
    <button class="btn-subscribe">
        <%= link_to 'SUBSCRIBE TO ICAL', area_show_url(protocol: :webcal, format: :ics, id: Area.find(@selected_area.id)) %>
      </button>
```

thanks for you help and time

Comment: How does this exactly work on a technical level? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Technical_specifications

Answer (score 1):

How it works:

Your website puts up a calendar feed (basically a .ics text/calendar file possibly produced in real time from latest data, no caching).  Hopefully this file contains valid RFC5545 data and thus shows any event updates as specified in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545 (Using UID and SEQUENCE and LAST-MODIFIED for each VEVENT modification)

Subscribing applications will check for any updates as and when suits them, as defined by their own algorithims.  They parse the .ics file and process the RFC5545 event definitions and update their systems accordingly.